# Mock response from different URLs with aiohttp

Tags: python, pytest, aiohttp

Let's say I have a function that gets 2 integers from different APIs:

```py
import aiohttp

async def my_func():
    with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        with session.get("https://url1.com/getA") as r:
            a = await r.text()

        with session.get("https://url2.com/getB") as r:
            b = await r.text()

        return int(a) + int(b)
```

How can I mock responses from both APIs when writing unit tests for my function? I'm using pytest.

Comment: there is a lot of useful information out there. have you tried anything? try usthig this https://realpython.com/testing-third-party-apis-with-mocks/

Answer (score 1):

You have come across one of the feedback loops of writing tests. When writing a test if you find yourself doing more than a normal amount of mocking/patching, it usually means your function that you are testing, is not optimally written. In your case there is no need for this function to hit *two* URLs in the same go. A better way to rewrite your code and then test it is shown below.

```
import aiohttp

async def my_func(url):
    with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        with session.get(url) as r:
            a = await r.text()

        return int(a)

async def my_adder(*urls):
    total = sum(await(url) for url in urls)
    return total
```

Then you would use [aioresponses](https://github.com/pnuckowski/aioresponses) to mock the URL calls. The [GitHub](https://github.com/pnuckowski/aioresponses#usage) page has excellent examples of just how to do that.

Please do note, if you decide to use this package I highly recommend revising your functions in the manner shown to make testing easier.